# How do I hide a div that has a ul with a certain id using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to hide any `<div>`'s that do not have a `<ul>` with a certain id.  I have a fiddle where I am trying this but it isn't working the way I expected. I can get all of them to hide but the one I want to continue showing isn't working.

HTML

```
<ul id="accordion">
    <li>
        <div style="background-color: rgb(109, 129, 27);" class="expand" title="Click to Expand">Zoos</div>
        <ul class="sortCat1" id="zoo">
            <li id="1"><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li id="2"><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li id="3"><a href="#">3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div style="background-color: rgb(109, 129, 27);" title="Click to Expand" class="expand">Attractions</div>
        <ul class="sortCat2" id="attractions">
            <li id="1"><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li id="2"><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li id="3"><a href="#">3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div style="background-color: rgb(109, 129, 27);" title="Click to Expand" class="expand">Dining &amp; Shopping</div>
        <ul class="sortCat3" id="dinShop">
            <li id="1"><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li id="2"><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li id="3"><a href="#">3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
if($('.expand ul').id == 'attractions'){
        $(this).css({'display': 'block'});
    }else{
        $('.expand').css({'display': 'none'});
    }
```

JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/27Wmm/

Comment: `id`'s should be unique

Comment: In your javascript, you are hiding the label where I think you are wanting to hide the UL that is under a certain label, not the label itself.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie -  If HTML5 you can use numbers but with CSS you have trouble without a [Workaround](http://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/)

Comment: @aldanux  I just typed this up really quick as an example didn't really even think about it. In my actual code for the site those are the names of locations.  Thanks for pointing it out in my example though you are correct!

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - I agree completely and I recommended too... but it's an opinion and not a fact.. :)

Comment: @Fogolicious If you take a look at your code, you'll find out, that there's no elements within `div`s, hence they can't have an `ul` with `#attractions` either.

Comment: I remove and reword my earlier statement to "It is recommended id's should not start with a number. Use classes instead (also not starting with a number)". They may work in HTML 5, but a) the world is still running HTML 4 and b) it makes less syntactic sense than using say `data-` attributes with numbers and leave IDs for meaningful, unique, readable, information. :)

Comment: Yes, the world is running in HTML 4 but it's headed to use HTML5. 

The HTML5.1 Nightly spec says [it's fine to start with digits](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-id-attribute). Truth be told `id`s starting with digits don't get styled.

In contrast with the HTML5 spec, the CSS spec says [it's NOT ok to start `id`s and `classes` with digits](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters).

But... you *CAN* style `id`s and `classes` that start with digits: http://jsfiddle.net/hrgg2/4/ - http://benfrain.com/when-and-where-you-can-use-numbers-in-id-and-class-names/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discussions of the non-merits of numeric ids aside...

Reading between the lines I think you wanted something like this (toggles open the UL associated with a labelled div):

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/27Wmm/1/

```
$(function () {
    $('#accordion').on('click', '.expand', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        // Show the sibling of the clicked div 
        $this.next().css({
            'display': 'inherit'
        });
        // Now hide all others sibling of the non-clicked divs
        $('.expand').not($this).next().css({
            'display': 'none'
        });
    });
});
```

With any type of menu, you would normally want to avoid any hard-coding of selections and have it operate on the item clicked (and other related  items not clicked).

You would also probably want to start only one (if any) not-collapsed which just means an initial style on them. e.g. in CSS

```
#accordion ul {
    display: none;
}
```

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/27Wmm/3/

### Update

If you want it to have specific startup behaviour, you can factor out the bit that does the work and call it on startup as well.

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/27Wmm/4/

```
var showThis = function ($this) {
    // Show the sibling of the clicked div 
    $this.next().css({
        'display': 'inherit'
    });
    // Now hide all others
    $('.expand').not($this).next().css({
        'display': 'none'
    });
}

$(function () {
    $('#accordion').on('click', '.expand', function () {
        showThis($(this));
    });
    showThis($('#attractions').prev());
});
```

### Yet another update

According to the comments, the desired behaviour is to simply show the attraction DIV and associated UL. If that were the case (I still have my doubts) you would change the above to this:

```
var showThis = function ($this) {
    // Show the div, then show the sibling of the clicked div 
    $this.css({
        'display': 'inherit'
    }).next().css({
        'display': 'inherit'
    });
    // Now hide all other divs and ULs
    $('.expand').not($this).css({
        'display': 'none'
    }).next().css({
        'display': 'none'
    });
}

$(function () {
    showThis($('#attractions').prev());
});
```

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/27Wmm/5/

This should be plenty to play with.

Comment: This is not the effect I was looking for.  I already have this working in the actual code.  Which I have here http://www.wildernessterritory.com/territory-map  What I am trying to do is make it so that when I pass this map a get variable all menu options except attractions are not visible.

Comment: Well that tells a different story :) So just keep the call to `showThis($('#attractions').prev());` and drop the other part. It will collapse all except attractions

Comment: I don't want to just collapse. I actually want to make it not visible.  Is it possible to make the <ul> and the <div> not visible?

Comment: Collapse is just a term... It is hiding the UL currently. The `showThis` function in the example is pretty much what you need already. If you want to also hide the div, it is in $this variable, so trivial to also hide and show. You need to explain very clearly what you want it to do, but I will take a guess and update answer again now.

Comment: Your final update is the solution I was looking for.  I understand the collapse term.  I didn't want it only to collapse, I wanted it basically to not be accessible to the user.  Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped (finally). Always best to spell out the problem in excruciating detail. You often find the solution yourself during the process of explaining it :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're expecting it to work, but I modified your HTML and JS to get something that I think works how you want:

```
<ul id="accordion">
<li>
    <div style="background-color: rgb(109, 129, 27);" class="expand" title="Click to Expand">Zoos
    <ul class="sortCat1" id="zoo">
        <li id="1"><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li id="2"><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li id="3"><a href="#">3</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div style="background-color: rgb(109, 129, 27);" title="Click to Expand" class="expand">Attractions
    <ul class="sortCat2" id="attractions">
        <li id="1"><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li id="2"><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li id="3"><a href="#">3</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <div style="background-color: rgb(109, 129, 27);" title="Click to Expand" class="expand">Dining &amp; Shopping
    <ul class="sortCat3" id="dinShop">
        <li id="1"><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li id="2"><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li id="3"><a href="#">3</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

```
$(".expand").each(function()
{
    if($('ul', this).attr('id') != "attractions")
    {
        $(this).css({'display': 'none'});
    }
});
```

Comment: I can't change the layout of the html.  The div element is the area that is like a header and I just want that to disappear if the ul is attractions.

Comment: I imagine you have found that this cannot possibly work by now? The ULs are siblings of the DIVs and not children.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie  Well even if it is a sibling then wouldn't that mean that something like .next() could be used in some way?

Comment: @Fogolicious: Of course, hence my own answer uses next().

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if($('.sortCat2').attr('id') == 'attractions'){
$('.sortCat2').css({'display': 'none'});
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/27Wmm/2/